# How to select a text (without tag) in a div using CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this :

```
<div class="foo">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    Some text I want to select using a CSS selector.
    <div class="subfoo">Some other text</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to select only "Some text I want to retrieve using a CSS selector" using a **single** expression of CSS selectors ?

Comment: There is no CSS selector that excludes inheritance to inner elements. You will have to overwrite unwanted inherited properties on the child elements.

Comment: Have you tried `.foo:not(.foo *)`? I'm unsure it this is possible.

Comment: @connexo Thanks for your answer, but that does not work : http://jsfiddle.net/qw70ok4b/, you are right I think that's impossible using just one single expression

Comment: @Reveclair check the answer I posted, I think this will be useful to you

Comment: I wasn't actually expecting it to work, but it's good you tried.

Comment: @connexo: That would be selecting any `.foo` that is itself not a descendant of another `.foo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to do in a clean manner with pure CSS.

As Vangel as suggested I recommend setting the styling for it in a `.foo` selector then apply overrides for other elements:

```
.foo{
  //Some text styles
}
.foo *{
  //Overriding styles
}
```

However the best option would be to make changes to the HTML to place the text in its own element so it can be styled in isolation:

```
<div class="foo">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <span>Some text</span>
    <div class="subfoo">Some other text</div>
</div>

.foo span
{
   //Some text styling
}
```

Comment: `.foo > *` would perhaps be better for "everything else", or even `.foo *` to catch any potential grandchildren

Comment: rather `.foo *:not(span)`

Comment: @jalooc Overrides wouldn't be needed if the element was in a `span`.

Answer (score 2):

You could just add

```
.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

and then override if you want different styles at span or `.subfoo`

Comment: Keep in mind, editing .foo will cause all of its children to have red text, unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I Will suggest you to use reverse methodology. 
Set inherit color to text which is not in the tag (red) and the different color for all text which is not in the tag.

```css
 .foo > *{
  color: black;
}
.parentColor{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentColor">
    <div class="foo">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        Some text I want to select using a CSS selector.
        <div class="subfoo">Some other text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/e8fb1jmn/)

Comment: The application of `color` is just an example. He might also be wanting to differentiate regarding an arbitrary number of other css properties which probably not all child elements have in common.

Comment: @connexo you are right, if the scope is large or he wanted separate color for each inner tag than he will have to overwrite the parent color.