# [css selector]How to select element after dd tag within strong tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<strong class="prc">
  <dd>
    <del>42,680$</del>
  </dd>
  38,412$
</strong>
```

I want to select `38,412`. But I don't know how to select only `38,412 without 42,680$`.

Now I got the result of `4,268,038,412` so it looks like a very huge number.

Comment: `DD` in `STRONG` is nonsense. The most logic way is to add any markup around new price.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var dd = $('dd').text();
var totalText = $('.prc').text();

console.log(totalText.replace(dd, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong class="prc">
  <dd id="dd">
    <del>42,680$</del>
  </dd>
  38,412$
</strong>
```

First grab the text from `strong` & `dd`, then replace the `dd` text from the strong text.

> This is a work around, may be a solution what you are looking for.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer to only jquery

```
$('strong').not('dd')
```

But I don't know any css selector.

for CSS :-

[How to select a text (without tag) in a div using CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719647/how-to-select-a-text-without-tag-in-a-div-using-css-selector)

Answer (score 0):

It is [not possible to style text nodes by themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688758/331043), however you may be able to solve your problem with overrides.

If you style your `strong` element the way you would like the text node styled, you can override it with the `dd` element, like so:

```
strong
{
    color: red;
}

strong dd
{
    color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go : We have a :not selector in CSS, so you can use it :

> strong:not('dd') {
>
> }

**Structure :**

> Element:not(selector) {
>       css declarations; }