# CSS Selector to get the immediate text

Tags: css

I have the following html fragment.

```
<p class="price">
    £5022.2
    <span class="sub-price tax-price">(£126.68nbsp;incl VAT)</span>
</p>
```

Is there a way to  just target the £5022.2 from the above html fragment ?

If i target the class price and the text it targets the text
that is a part of the span tag too

Comment: You could target the whole thing then reset the span styling.

Comment: Hi Haworth I am terribly confused about it .Do you mind giving me additional pointers please

Comment: this answer is useful too . https://stackoverflow.com/a/31719820/10749726

Comment: Are you allowed to alter the HTML? If so just bung that in its own span and style that. If not, set the style you want the price to be and then reset anything in the .price span that you didn’t want changed.

Comment: Nope I can't alter that html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by adapting any other child in `.price`:

```css
.price {
  color: red;
}
.price > * {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p class="price">
    £5022.2
    <span class="sub-price tax-price">(£126.68nbsp;incl VAT)</span>
</p>
```

Comment: This would be a better solution.

Comment: Haha clever very clever but I would be still looking to extract only £5022.2 if possible :)

Comment: What do you mean by "extract" ? You don't want that the span be shown ?

Comment: I want to get the value £5022.2 in a variable

Comment: OK but then, it is different problem, as here you just talk about **CSS**, CSS wont get this value, it is not its purpose. Go for a JS solution or any other language that could help to "get" or extract value.

Comment: Thanks MaxiGui for the help and also for this knowledge byte :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your problem is below.

You should wrap the number with another span and then you can solve this.

```
<p class="price">
    <span class="num">£5022.2</span>
    <span class="sub-price tax-price">(£126.68nbsp;incl VAT)</span>
</p>


.price >.num{
 /*styles goes here*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks Samitha but no luck with this

Comment: I’ll wrap with new span and now it’s working. I think it’s no issue for the code.