# Hide text in a span

Tags: css, hide

I'm looking how to hide a text ("Tag") into a span like this :

```
<span class="tagged_as">
      Tag : 
      <a href="product-tag/enfant/" rel="tag">Enfant</a>, 
      <a href="product-tag/jeu-prime/" rel="tag">Jeu primé</a>
</span>
```

I tried to remove the text but I don't want to change something that a don't make...
With css, i tried different things like font-size 0 but font of the href is also changed...
visibility hidden... not working...

I don't know how to select only the text and not the "a" part.

Comment: With your html i think you can't. you can set font-size :0 to class .tagged_as and set a font-size for the children link

Comment: This question is related to what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31719647/4652564

Comment: You have to be careful because depending on the CSS properties, screen readers can't read the text. Ideally you want that to happen to have a good code.

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to do it tinkering with transforms. You can push the parent out of the viewport using `translateX(-100vw)` on the `span` and `translateX(100vw)` on `a`. Kind of a weird way, but you will not ever see it, provided the website scrolls **vertically**.

**Changing the font-size to 0 and adding it back to `a` is more reliable (and elegant), but this solution might be helpful, if you don't know the texts font-size or if it is variable.**

```css
span {
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
  display: block;
}

span a {
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="tagged_as">
      Tag : 
      <a href="product-tag/enfant/" rel="tag">Enfant</a>, 
      <a href="product-tag/jeu-prime/" rel="tag">Jeu primé</a>
</span>
```